# Fetching data with hook takes too long time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, web-applications, react-hooks

I am trying to fetch and map an array with 350 object's elements. I decided to use Hook and useEffect, to re render my dataTable component since mapping is done. Unfortunately, the whole process takes enormous amount of time, and it makes page unresponsive. After 1-2 minutes, table shows up and after few seconds it disappears. After that page is still unresponsive. Could someone explain why it happens, and give me some workaround? I would be grateful.
Code below:

```
const Employees = (props) => {
const [developers, setDevelopers] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
});

const columns = [
    {
        name: "Emloyee",
        selector: "name",
        sortable: true,
    },
    {
        name: "Team ",
        selector: "team",
        sortable: true,
    },
    {
        name: "Email ",
        selector: "email",
        sortable: true,
    },
];

const fetchData = () => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3128/employees", {
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        }
    })
        .then((response) => {
            mapData(response.data.developers);
            console.log("I am here!");
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log(e));
};

const mapData = (jsonData) => {
    jsonData.forEach((x) => {
        let newDeveloper = {
            name: x.userId,
            team: x.team,
            email: x.userId + "@mail.com",
        };
        setDevelopers((developers) => [...developers, newDeveloper]);
    });
};

return <DataTable title="Employees" columns={columns} data={developers}/>;
```

};

Comment: Is the network response taking a long time? I can't imagine mapping ~350 objects taking much time/effort. What debugging have you done to see what is slow? Why not just map the json data and set state once versus forEach'ing and setting state for each element at a time?

Comment: To be honest, I am not proficient in webs app debugging, it looks like, there are some troubles with re rending and hook state updating.

Comment: Likely it is `F12` to open browser's development tools, you should see a tab labeled "Network". From here you should be able to see how long requests are taking. If you skip the axios call and map in generic "random" data, is it still slow to update? You need to figure out what part is slow then dig in on *that* bit.

Comment: "Why not just map the json data and set state once versus forEach'ing and setting state for each element at a time?"

That worked out! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`useEffect` without dependency array will run on every render, so in your case, you are stuck in an infinite loop which cause page to become unresponsive

solution:

```
const fetchData = useCallback(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3128/employees", {
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        }
    })
        .then((response) => {
            mapData(response.data.developers);
            console.log("I am here!");
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log(e));
},[]);
```

```
const mapData = useCallback((jsonData) => {
    jsonData.forEach((x) => {
        let newDeveloper = {
            name: x.userId,
            team: x.team,
            email: x.userId + "@kuehne-nagel.com",
        };
        setDevelopers((developers) => [...developers, newDeveloper]);
    });
},[]);
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
},[fetchData]); // pass dependency array here in useEffect
```

Comment: After that I've got an error: " ReferenceError: Cannot access 'fetchData' before initialization"

Comment: shift `useEffect` after defining both `fetchData` and `mapData`

Comment: That worked out, but there is still the same performance issue :/

Comment: Not a single one

Comment: Then check your network tab if your http request is taking long to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @DrewReese and @SarthakAggarwal , I've got a solution:

```
const Employees = (props) => {
const [developers, setDevelopers] = useState([]);


const columns = [
    {
        name: "Emloyee",
        selector: "name",
        sortable: true,
    },
    {
        name: "Team ",
        selector: "team",
        sortable: true,
    },
    {
        name: "Email ",
        selector: "email",
        sortable: true,
    },
];

const fetchData = useCallback(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3128/employees", {
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        }
    })
        .then((response) => {
            mapData(response.data.developers);
            console.log("I am here!");
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log(e));
}, []);

const mapData = (jsonData) => {
  let table = [];
    jsonData.forEach((x) => {
        let newDeveloper = {
            name: x.userId,
            team: x.team,
            email: x.userId + "@mail.com",
        };
        table = [...table,newDeveloper];
        //setDevelopers((developers) => [...developers, newDeveloper]);
    });
  setDevelopers((developers) => table);
};

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
}, [fetchData]);


return <DataTable title="Employees" columns={columns} data={developers}/>;
```

};

Thanks a lot !